# ng-repeat and ng-hide on each

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in group.Subgroups" ng-hide="value.ToBeDeleted" ng-include="'groupTemplate.html'">
```

How can I make this affect all items in group.Subgroups[]?, and not just the whole div?

Comment: add filter to ng-repeat

Comment: This way of using ng-include is not good for performance!

Comment: better Use ng-show .. it is quicker than ng-hide there is a difference

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but it should be something like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in group.Subgroups">
    <div ng-if="!value.ToBeDeleted" ng-include="'groupTemplate.html'">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Use ng-if to prevent the template getting rendered into the DOM.

Comment: well this is close. But the group.Subgroups can also have subgroups and so on. So what can I do to make sure that this affects the children's children's children?

Comment: This is called a tree. Have a look at https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree

Comment: So will I have to add this comp to my solution?

Comment: If you want childrens of childrens of childrens .. to be displayed. Yes you have to use some sort of tree. You can mark it as solution or upvote, as far it helped you.